# Trace of an algebraic element

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite algebraic extension of fields, $\Omega$ be an algebraic closure of $L$ and $y\in\Omega $ an algebraic separable element over $K$ not belonging to $L$. Does $\mathrm{Tr}_{L[y]/L}(y)$ belong to $K$?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The trace of any element of $L(y)$ down to $L$ belongs to $L$, and hence must also belong to $K$, since $L$ is contained in $K$. Are you sure this is what you want to ask?

Comment: My mistake: I meant $L/K$...

Comment: You should need $L$ and $K[y]$ to be linearly disjoint, I think.

Comment: Not necessarily. Take $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and $y=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. Then $\mathrm{Tr}_{L[y]/L}(y) = \mathrm{Tr}_{L[y]/L}(\sqrt{2}) + \mathrm{Tr}_{L[y]/L}(\sqrt{3}) = 2\sqrt{2}\notin K$.

Comment: If $a = \mathrm{Tr}_{L[y]/L}(y) \in K^*$ then for $c \in L$, $\mathrm{Tr}_{L[\frac{c}{a}y]/L}(\frac{c}{a}y) = c$ thus your question doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: @reuns: But the trace could be zero.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In characteristic $0$, if the trace of $y$ is zero then replace it by $y+l$